# Count down timer in Wordpress using Jquery and Custom User Meta Fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create a count down timer to an event (linked to a user) in Wordpress.

So far I have managed to create the count down using jquery by manually entering the date of the event.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5M4G/)

However I want this date to be dynamically used based on when the users event is i.e. using the custom meta field for date for the user. Please help in terms on how I can achieve this by calling the custom meta-field.

Jquery:

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

// format countdown string + set tag value
countdown.innerHTML = days + "d," + hours + "h," + minutes + "m," + seconds + "s";   

}, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: *"custom meta field for date"*, please explain this. Is it User Meta or Post Meta?

Comment: Looks like you have 2 completely different issues, and we should only ask 1 question per Question. One of them already answered by KoalBear. You should mark this one as solved and open a new one detailing how you are including the scripts in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i managed to figure it out. So as per the Javascript, the countdown was working If i manually added the date to `var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();`.

I then needed to collect the event date for each user and replace it in this function. To get the event date stored in the user meta i used the following code:

`<?php $user_id = get_current_user_id(); $key = 'Your Event Date'; $single = true; $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); echo $user_last; ?>`

I then added this function in the Javascript to get the countdown working:

```
var target_date = new Date( '<?php $user_id = get_current_user_id(); $key = 'Event Date';    $single = true; $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); echo $user_last; ?>' ).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what you are trying to do, but I think something like this.

If you could output something like the following between script tags.

Javascript:

```
countdownDate = 'Aug 15, 2019';
```

And the use it somewhere else like you already do.

Javascript:

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date(countdownDate).getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I am trying to do. I want to convert the date stored in the Meta field for the user and use it the Javascript function. Any idea on how i can do this?

Comment: Ok so i have somewhat managed to this..In my Javascript, I replaced `var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();` with `var target_date = new Date( '<?php 
  $user_id = 5;
  $key = 'Event Date';
  $single = true;
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo  $user_last; 
?>' ).getTime();`

where the code fetches the event date for user with id=5. Just need to figure out how i can do this for the current user only and make the user id variable and not fixed